# templated type with no template variable and other templated type using such

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I can't exactly understand C++ code lines below.
Why does line 1 use template when T is not appearing in line 1? Does it mean when struct bits are declared with certain template type, (like `bits<float>`), it just does `typdef unsigned char type;` inside the struct?

In line 2, does it mean if I declare `struct bits<const float>`, it also intitlaizes a struct `bits<float>` using line 1? meaning bits is like `bits<float>` ?
I would appreciate if someone explains what this code is doing or refer me to a good reference about this topic.

```
    /// Type traits for floating point bits.
    template<typename T> struct bits { typedef unsigned char type; };  // line 1
    template<typename T> struct bits<const T> : bits<T> {};  // line 2
    template<typename T> struct bits<volatile T> : bits<T> {};  // line 3
    template<typename T> struct bits<const volatile T> : bits<T> {};  // line 4
```

Comment: This is in no way related to **C**. C and C++ are completely different languages on bit level - there are no templates in C. Please stop spamming tags.

Comment: I suppose there are some other (full) specializations, else the partial specialization are mostly useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason that a template parameter has to be used by the template. The unused parameter can be used to delineate different versions of the templated class/function/variable that have nothing to do with the template parameter itself.

```
template<int N> bool f();
template<1> bool f(){return true;};
template<0> bool f(){return false;};
```

In line 2, `bits<const T>` is inheriting from `bits<T>`. It isn't initializing an instance of `bits<T>`, but gaining all the pieces of it as if it were part of itself. All that happens when `bits<const T>` is initialized is that it will define a type `type`, like it does for `bits<T>`.

Comment: Oh, I see, I forgot it's C++ ad `: bits<T>` indicates the inheritance. (but in my question I'm saying like `bits<T>` is base class :) ). And from your answer, I understand the first line is just the basic (mother class) template irreleavant to no specific type and the follwing lines are the `specialization` of the template class! Thank!

Comment: Then, can we write the first line as `template<typename T> struct bits<T> { typedef unsigned char type; };` as well?